# Magmi is not updating products

Tags: magento, magmi

I have installed Magmi on a store running Magento 1.7 It works brilliantly to import the products with my CSV.

I then alter the price values in the same CVS, re-upload and run Magmi to update but nothing changes in the Magneto Products list.

I have custom options and image processor plugins running.

I've looked through the docs and think I'm doing everything correctly.

If any one has info on this its greatly appreciated.

If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Further to the above I have discovered it is updating the info, as it is shown on product page, but in the backend it is not shown. If I update through backend this is not shown on product page on front end?

Comment: OK Found it was updating base store. But on backend view not showing change.

Comment: Have now deleted other store views as not used and now have to go in and save each product after update to save changes. Seen other have had this error but can't remember the fix if there is one?

Comment: Make sure you also include `admin` in the store column.